# Loop within string formatting in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn string formatting in Python and I was wondering if you can do something like this:

```
print(f'{element[i].key}: {element[i]}\n{element[i].key}:{element[i]}\' for i in range(2))
```

Basically, I want to run a for loop within a print so I can iterate and print different values within a dictionary. I feel like I have seen something like this before but I have no idea what the name of it is or how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
my_dict = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
print('\n'.join(f'{key}: {value}' for key, value in my_dict.items()))
```

But remember that putting everything on a single line isn't a goal in itself. It's OK to aim for efficiency or performance, but readability and clarity are sometimes even more important.

Answer (score 4):

A basic list comprehension with f-string will do the job:

```
    [print(f'{key}:{value}') for key, value in my_dict.items()]
```

Comment: Note that this has the overhead of calling print repeatedly. This also means that it doesn't work in cases where there is no linefeed required after each value printed. It's basically (ab)using the list comprehension to put a regular for loop on a single line. Very clear and easy to read though, but so would a 2-line `for .. print` be.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running a for loop within a print, you should put a print inside of a for loop.

For example:

```py
for i in range(2):
    print(f'{element[i].key}: {element[i]}\n{element[i].key}:{element[i]}\')
```